# Obtener el nombre de una clase generic en una interfaz en java

Tags: java, clase, interface, genericos

Tengo el siguiente caso:

```
public interface CustomRepository<T> {
...
}

public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T> implements CustomRepository<T>{
//Como puedo obtener el nombre de la Clase T
}

//Por ejemplo si uso la clase Usuario, deberia obtener el nombre usuario
public interface UsuarioRepository extends CustomRepository<Usuario>{

}
```

Comment: Prueba con `System.out.println(T.class.getCanonicalName());`

Comment: @A.Cedano me sale error y el siguiente mensaje: Illegal class literal for the type parameter T

Comment: prueba en el constructor con System.out.println(this.type)

Comment: @x-rw no se puede, me sale error de sintaxis

Answer (score 3):

No puedes verlo directamente debido a que el compilador elimina los tipos una vez compilado, el llamado [`borrado de tipo`](https://es.quora.com/Qu%C3%A9-es-borrado-de-tipo-en-Java).

Sin embargo puedes pasárselo al constructor al crearlo, asi guarda el tipo de clase para poder usarlo después. Un ejemplo:

```
public class CustomRepositoryImpl<T> implements CustomRepository<T>{

    private Class<T> type; // Variable con el tipo

    // Guardamos el tipo que le pasamos en el constructor
    public CustomRepositoryImpl(Class<T> type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Clase que devuelve un string del tipo
    public String getClassName(){
        return this.type.getCanonicalName();
    }
}
```

Así, por ejemplo, si lo creamos con el tipo String:

```
CustomRepositoryImpl<String> test = new CustomRepositoryImpl<String>(String.class);
```

Al llamar a `test.getClassName()` nos devolverá `java.lang.String`